# Firebase custom token in NodeJS (fastify framework)

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I would like to create a custom token from my fastify server.

Now, I am reading the following, exceptionally poor, guide:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

They have this (incomplete in my opinion) example:

```
const uid = 'some-uid';

getAuth()
  .createCustomToken(uid)
  .then((customToken) => {
    // Send token back to client
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
  });
```

The first thing I do not understand is where the method getAuth() comes from. There is zero explanation in the official documentation.
My guess would be that it comes from the firebase-admin. However I do not understand how to use it.

The second non-sense thing, related to the above is when I created a project in firebase console I got the following:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "api_key",
  authDomain: "xyz",
  projectId: "xyz",
  storageBucket: "xyz",
  messagingSenderId: "000",
  appId: "0xyz",
  measurementId: "xyz0"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

However I do not understand how to use it in the firebase-admin.

Even if I do the following:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

I get the message:

> errorInfo: {
> code: 'auth/invalid-credential',
> message: 'Failed to determine service account. Make sure to initialize the SDK with a service account credential. Alternatively
> specify a service account with iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob
> permission. Original error: Error: Error while making request:
> getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata. Error code: ENOTFOUND'   },
> codePrefix: 'auth'

Any help would be much appreciated as I have wasted a lot of time due to the incompleteness of the firebase documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the client-side SDK (`firebase`) and the server-side Admin SDK (`firebase-admin`), which is not a good idea.

To mint a custom token you (only) need the Admin SDK, so get rid of the other `firebase` dependency. Then [initialize the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) as described in the documentation, which means you provide it with administrative credentials (in one of the ways [shown here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#before_you_begin)) that allow it to (amongst others) [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).